# solr autosuggestion with tokenization

Tags: solr

I am trying the autosuggestion with tokenization. If I provide 'solr', I should get results of 'Apache Solr' too. The below configuration provides results as 'Apache solr' if I provide 'apache'. I need a tokenized wildcard search.

#### managed-schema

```
<fieldType name="custom_text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>        
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="content" type="custom_text" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>
```

Applying request handler as below:

```
<searchComponent name="customsuggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">customsuggester-content</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">content</str>
        <str name="weightField">price</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">custom_text</str>
        <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponen>
<requestHandler name="/customsuggest" class="solr.SearchHandler"
      startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="suggest">true</str>
        <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
        <str>customsuggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

When I tried with the below url, no results getting out from that:

```
http://host:port/solr/collection-name/customsuggest?suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=customsuggester-content&indent=on&wt=json&suggest.q=solr
```

When I tried with below url, I am getting results:

```
http://host:port/solr/collection-name/customsuggest?suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=customsuggester-content&indent=on&wt=json&suggest.q=apache
```

Comment: Following [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) simple rules could improve your questions a lot. I suggest to follow them. I partially fixed your question now, but I can't be with you every time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the "AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory" lookupImpl. It provides suggestions that contain your token at any position in the suggestion content.

```
<searchComponent name="customsuggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
<lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">customsuggester-content</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">content</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">custom_text</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
</lst>
```

You can find all the available lookup implementations at [Solr Suggester Overview](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester)