# solr auto-suggestion with multible where clauses

Tags: solr

Not sure if it is a relevant query to post, but want to understand auto-suggestion is suitable option for location based search as I am looking for specific requirement. The requirement is, from a specified geo location, want to search for providers(be it doctor with specialty or hospitals) using auto suggestion.

As part of suggestion, I need to pass geo location with search key, the search key would be a doctor’s name or doctor’s specialty or hospital name or hospital address, the suggester would provide the results on the basis of geo distance in ascending order.

The weightage option would be calculated on the basis of distance by inverse value.

I posted earlier a query here ([solr autosuggestion with tokenization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417204/solr-autosuggestion-with-tokenization)), this post is relevant to my earlier query.

Regards
Venkata Madhu

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add more logic to the suggestions that you're going to show is probably a good idea to use normal queries instead of the suggest component.

For instance take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/cominvent/autocomplete/blob/master/solr-home/ac/conf/solrconfig.xml) is a (bit outdated) example of using a normal solr core to store suggestions and do suggest-like queries. Meaning you can do partial match queries on that index and add the custom scoring logic that you want. Keep in mind that it doesn't need to be a separated core you could just copy data from the fields that you have in a separate field used only for generating the suggestions.

In this case, you'll only need to add/edit the score function used to add your own logic (`geodist`) or even do a hard sort on the distance.